# Inverting a gray scale image with the pixel values stored in an array in C

Tags: c

I currently am doing homework and I have this question that I am unable to understand. I am **NOT** asking for someone to code for me or anything, I just find that I am unable to understand what my question is asking for. If someone can help me understand what should be done, then I can code it ;p!

Here is the question:

**Invert the image intensities, so that black becomes white and vice
   versa, and light shades of grey become the corresponding dark
   shade.**

Now, I know that white is 0 and black is 255 and all I have to do is swap them in the array, but what does it mean in the last part where it asks me to switch the light shades of grey to dark shades of grey. Assuming it is referring to the remaining 1-254 numbers (pixels), what am I supposed to swap? If someone can explain to me how to do this then it would be great. Again, I am not looking for someone to code for me, I just want to know what it is asking for so I can myself code it.

Comment: I doubt you're expected to swap any pixels around... just change the value in each one, so that it's opposite intensity (so that the new value is as far below 255 as the old value was above 0).

Comment: In human language I'm guessing they mean if it was positive intensity 10, you want it to be negative intensity 10 in the inverted image. So if it was 10 it should be 245 (i.e. 255-value)? Do you have any examples that came with the question, either in image or numeric form?

Comment: Opposite intensity as in opposite of a number? O.o?

Comment: 0 => 255, 1 => (255 - 1) => 254, 2 => (255 - 2) => 253, etc.

Comment: Oh, really now .... I guess I was under the wrong assumption of swapping pixels. Did you guys learn this from C or is this just knowledge with greyscal images?

Comment: Programming is useless unless you know at least *something* about whatever it is your program works on/for.  Constantly having to learn about new things on an as-needed basis is one of the things that makes programmers such interesting people :)

Answer (score 2):

The homework does not even mention the word "swap" so forget all about it. It clearly states that the grayscale should be inverted.

This is how you would do it for the *first* pixel:

```
image[0] = 255 - image[0];
```